# How do I fix this regular expression for my string?

Tags: expression

Are there any tools out there that will build a generic regular expression for me if it's given a specific string as input?

At the moment **I"ll settle for an actual regex** instead of a tool.

Note that in my case I can use HOST in angle brackets to represent the IP address in the regex.  My goal is to build a regex for the tool called "fail2ban".

Lets say my string is 
[2012-11-06 22:52:40] NOTICE[4339] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"202"' failed for '111.111.11.1:9546' - Wrong password

(It looks like this forum is apparently stripping out symbols and/or otherwise messing with my string so I'll use the following conventions so you can see what it's supposed to say:
DQ to represent a DOUBLE QUOTE  "
LAB to represent a LEFT ANGLE BRACKET <
RAB to represent a RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET >
AT to represent an at sign @
)

Using the above conventions:

[2012-11-06 22:52:40] NOTICE[4339] chan_sip.c: Registration from 'DQ 202 DQ LAB sip:202 AT emailAddress RAB' failed for '111.111.11.1:9546' - Wrong password

Note that I have added spaces between symbols to increase readability.  They are not part of the original string.

I have tried NOTICE.* .*: Registration from '.*' failed for ':.*' - Wrong password

and:
NOTICE.* .*: Registration from '\".*\"' failed for ':.*' - Wrong password

What is the proper regex please?

Thank you in advance

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Sidenote: If none already exist, it sure would be nice if someone could build a tool to automate building a regular expression given a particular string.

Here's what I'm thinking.

The string could be easily parsed by the following C library functions `isalphanum(c), isalpha(c), isdigit(c), ispunct(c), isspace(c)`.

The hard part is building a regular expression generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`NOTICE.+: Registration from '.+' failed for '.+' - Wrong password`

The tool I used to flesh that out was [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

EDIT:

I Googled for "regex generator" and came across [this result](http://txt2re.com/). That is probably what you are looking for (self: adds link to bookmarks)

Comment: Thank you.  That worked, but I'm perplexed.   From a random source: * (star) Repeats the previous item zero or more times. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is not matched at all.   + (plus) Repeats the previous item once or more. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is matched only once.  <continued next post for lack of characters left>

Comment: So, my regex used .* which matched zero or more characters, yours matched 1 or more characters.  Why does yours work but mine doesn't?  I've seen the tool you mentioned and quite frankly I didn't understand how to use it for my purposes.  In fact, I still don't.

Comment: Removed the space before the first colon and removed the colon in the second single quote group.  Another equivalent for the second quote group would be "'.+:.+'".  In regexes like these, I use '+' instead of '\*' because I am expecting at least one character in there.  With the regex I gave you, it should work with either '+' or '\*'

Comment: So the bottom line is essentially that I had an extra space?  Unreal.  I spent a dozen hours on it and I didn't see it.  Thank you for saving my sanity.  And thank you for the pointer to the tool.  It looks pretty amazing.  Much appreciated for both.